# Understanding the Coulomb term in the semi-empirical mass formula

Tags: nuclear-physics, coulombs-law, strong-force

Here's a passage I am not understanding:

> The tendency to an excess of neutrons at large mass numbers is a Coulomb repulsion effect. Because a given nucleon interacts with only a small number of its neighbours through the strong force, the amount of energy tied up in strong-force bonds between nucleons increases just in proportion to $A$.

I'm having difficulty in understanding as to why the amount of energy tied up in strong force bonds is proportional to $A$ (Atomic mass number).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [semi-empirical mass formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Semi-empirical_mass_formula) you are talking about gets its name from the fact that parts of it are obtained empirically.

As for the first term, Weizsäcker observed that the binding energy per nucleon ($E_B / A$) was approximately constant for large nuclei. Therefore he concluded that

$$ \frac{E_B}{A} \sim const. \quad\Rightarrow\quad E_B \sim const. A $$